# Typescript: filter a union based on a condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an union of API names, e.g.:

```
type ApiNames = 'getUser' | 'getUsers' | 'getPosts';
```

I want to filter this union to get API names with a specific property. E.g. I have the params for each API:

```
type ApiParams = {
  getUser: {
    userId: number,
  },
  getUsers: {
    cursor?: number,
  },
  getPosts: {
    cursor?: number,
  },
}
```

I'm trying to get just the API names that have "cursor" as a param. I'd like the output to be:

```
type ApiNamesWithCursor = 'getUsers' | 'getPosts';
```

I tried the following:

```
type ApiNamesWithCursor = ApiParams[ApiNames] extends { cursor?: number }
  ? ApiNames
  : never;

type ApiNamesWithCursor<Name extends ApiNames> = ApiParams[Name] extends { cursor?: number }
  ? Name
  : never;
```

**Edit:**

It looks like this works, but is there an easier way?

```
type ApiNamesWithCursor = {
  [Name in ApiNames]: ApiParams[Name] extends {
    cursor?: number;
  }
    ? Name
    : never;
}[ApiNames];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have more generic solution:

```js
type ApiNames = 'getUser' | 'getUsers' | 'getPosts';


type ApiParams = {
    getUser: {
        userId: number,
    },
    getUsers: {
        cursor?: number,
    },
    getPosts: {
        cursor?: number,
    },
}

type Filter<Obj, Param extends string> = {
    [P in keyof Obj]: Required<Obj[P]> extends Record<Param, unknown> ? P: never
}[keyof Obj]

type Result = Filter<ApiParams, 'cursor'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWA5AhgWwgZygXigcgHMJgBVDCAJzygB98jTyKNq7DiAFAew2BYG4AUMNCRYCDsgposuAN6CoSqAzKUAXFAXKdUAK5MAkgBNNAOz2oARpQA0i5QF97O1UwybtupQGM9zLgoAfnNLGwoXJ0ilBm5eDy0Hbz8A4NDrOySoZ0FHEXBoADF4ABtgSgAeAHkrACtbKElpVCgIAA9ys2MsXgp4MwIAPhxEnQBtDih%20qABrCBAuADMoGtqAXU0AJQgARz14CghjarqJteH2zu6obZ9A46a0Br0zGbMuAHczYaDG8wgAG6UXJjOYLZarNb5MTbDB6MojYplSpweCPVAYBp4FIYQJ4QaCIA)

Explanation:

- `Required<Obj[P]>` means, that I want to ingore `optional flag - ?` and will treat property as a required